# Roboelectric and Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, robolectric

I've been trying to do it for a few days, with no result. I need to set up Robolectric in Android Studio (0.8.9, latest version).
I followed different tutorials [Android Unit and Integration testing](https://github.com/thecodepath/android_guides/wiki/Android-Unit-and-Integration-testing#robolectric), [Roboelectric installation for Unit testing](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Robolectric-Installation-for-Unit-Testing), [Android Gradle app with Roboelectric](http://blog.blundell-apps.com/android-gradle-app-with-robolectric-junit-tests/), [How to run Roboelectric JUnit tests](http://blog.blundell-apps.com/how-to-run-robolectric-junit-tests-in-android-studio/) but always got some kind of error.

So I created module specially for testing:

[image]

[image]

**Kedzoh (Project) build.gradle**:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-    projects/modules.
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
    classpath 'org.robolectric:robolectric-gradle-plugin:0.12.+'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}
```

**app build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.dev.kedzoh'
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 14
    versionName '1.6.7'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.42'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.6.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.3'
// You must install or update the Support Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0-rc1'
compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:+'
compile 'com.larswerkman:HoloColorPicker:1.4'
}
```

**kedzoh-tests build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.6.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.3'
// You must install or update the Support Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0-rc1'
compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:+'
compile 'com.larswerkman:HoloColorPicker:1.4'

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.+'
testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.2'
}
```

At this point I cannot import Robolectric classes, it gives me error. When I add *apply plugin: 'robolectric'* to **kedzoh-tests build.gradle**, it asks for *'android' plugin*. After I add it, it complains there is no Manifest and fails to build.
I'm not sure that this is the right configuration, since it never worked really. Could anyone give some advice how to set Robolectric in Android Studio, please?

**EDIT:**

I tried the answer below, but still stuck with "Class not found" error:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There already different project templates for robolectric. Did you try https://github.com/nenick/android-gradle-template ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you maybe making your life more difficult and complicated by creating your test module outside of the main 'app' module. Most of the tutorials I have seen have an androidTest folder in the app module that can contain your Robolectric tests. All of the older tutorials based around Eclipse I have seen, seem to instruct us to create test modules separate to the main project.

If I were using Robolectric I would setup the project like I have created for you https://github.com/marcthomas2013/Kedzoh. I would use the androidTest folder to put my tests and configure the gradle files as follows.

Note that the dependencies for the tests are included using the androidTestCompile declaration and application dependencies are declared using just compile.

Another item in this gradle file is the robolectric section where it is including and excluding classes in the androidTest folder. Anything that isn't in the espresso folder will be run using the gradlew test target and everything including the espresso folder will be run when calling gradlew connectedAndroidTest target.

```
app gradle file
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'robolectric'

android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 18
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        androidTest {
            setRoot('src/androidTest')
        }
    }
}

robolectric {
    include '**/*Test.class'
    exclude '**/espresso/**/*.class'
}

dependencies {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:2.0.1'

    androidTestCompile('junit:junit:4.11') {
        exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
    }
    // Espresso
    androidTestCompile files('libs/espresso-1.1.jar')
    androidTestCompile files('libs/testrunner-1.1.jar')
    androidTestCompile files('libs/testrunner-runtime-1.1.jar')
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.guava:guava:14.0.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.1.0'
    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.1'
    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1'
    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.1'
    androidTestCompile('org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3') {
        exclude module: 'classworlds'
        exclude module: 'commons-logging'
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
        exclude module: 'maven-artifact'
        exclude module: 'maven-artifact-manager'
        exclude module: 'maven-error-diagnostics'
        exclude module: 'maven-model'
        exclude module: 'maven-project'
        exclude module: 'maven-settings'
        exclude module: 'plexus-container-default'
        exclude module: 'plexus-interpolation'
        exclude module: 'plexus-utils'
        exclude module: 'wagon-file'
        exclude module: 'wagon-http-lightweight'
        exclude module: 'wagon-provider-api'
    }
    androidTestCompile 'com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.+'
}
```

**project build file**
Here we include the robolectric class path so that we can use the robolectric gradle commands in the config file above.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'
        classpath 'org.robolectric:robolectric-gradle-plugin:0.11.+'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Can you explain what errors that you are having as there could be many possible errors based on how you are working, also is there a particular reason for creating a separate test module.

The project that I have provided is based on the deck-gradle setup (https://github.com/robolectric/deckard-gradle) there are a number of tips in here about JUnit conflicts etc. that you could be having trouble with.

Once you have got this far in order to be able to debug the unit test in the application you will have to manually tweak the classpath when launching the test (Not Pretty at all!), based on the information in this article https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Robolectric-Installation-for-Unit-Testing

You will need to run your unit test, wait for it to fail, copy the -classpath parameter and it's value (It will be quite long and starts and finishes with ") and copy this into your VM Options in your run configuration, then at the end of that classpath add a ; or a : depending on your OS path delimeter and add the path to your test classes which will be something like `<ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_PROJECT>/build/test-classes` this will add your test classes to the class path and then Android Studio should be able to run them.

This is also assuming that the steps to run the `gradle testClasses` has been done from the article http://blog.blundell-apps.com/how-to-run-robolectric-junit-tests-in-android-studio/

Comment: I updated the question, please take a look. I followed your advice but get "Class not found" error

Comment: Does it work if you run 'gradlew clean test' from the command line? i.e. can you get it to work outside of AndroidStudio?

Comment: I have updated the end of the answer to include how to get the unit tests to run from within Android Studio. It isn't pretty as it is basically a class path issue, for some reason the working directory is being ignored.

Comment: when I try gradlew clean test it returns " java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException", see the screenshot from the EDIT

Comment: I added Build test classes, but it never worked anyway

Comment: Can you have a look at the test results file to see if there is more detail to the java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException as I can't recreate that using the github project on my system. Have you changed the project from the default clone on GitHub?

Comment: I already have my working repo, so I try to integrate Robolectrics within it. It is so error prone that I leave it for now. Thanks for help anyway!